# How to interpret domain of a function where the input is scalar to the power vector.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, machine-learning, function-spaces

From the paper that introduced PointNet(Qi et al,2016).

We have:

$f(\{x_1,...,x_n\}) \approx g(h(x_1),...,h(x_n)),$

where $f: 2^{\mathbb{R}^N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, and $h: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^K$ is symmetirc function.

My question is:

what does $2^{\mathbb{R}^N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ exactly mean?
I am confused about $2^{\mathbb{R}^N}$. I am aware of the fact it is a set of cardinality two to the power vector of real numbers of dimension N.

Comment: ${\mathbb{R}^N}$ seems to be the set of $n$-uples of reals.

Comment: Thus $2^{\mathbb{R}^N}$ is the *power-set* of the previous set,  i.e. the set whose elements are sets of $n$-uples.

Comment: The above provided that $N$ is a number and not $\mathbb N$ (the set of *natural* numbers) ...

Comment: Do you see the difference between $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, an $n$-uple of numbers, and $\{ x_1,\ldots, x_n \}$ a set of $n$ numbers ?

Comment: $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is a function with $n$ arguments ($n$ numbers) while $f( \{ x_1,\ldots, x_n \})$ has only one argument : a set of $n$ numbers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I see it is set, but I still do not see why 2 is used to refer to powerset. I understand that $2^x$ is the size of the space.

Comment: The power-set $\mathcal P(A)$ is also denoted with $2^A$ because the power set is equivalent to the set of all function from $A$ to $2 = \{ 0,1 \}$. Consider a subset $B$ of $A$ as a characteristic function that for each element $a$ of $A$ either outputs $1$ (YES) if $a \in B$ or outputs $0$ (NO) id $a \notin B$.

Comment: I already thought of it this way, but it does seem to make sense to me in the paper. But you are right this how things are defined.

Comment: Ok I guess it means that for any set from 0 to N points the function takes, it outputs a scalar(real number).